# android: BOOT_COMPLETED receiver causes crash

Tags: android

I have a receiver to react when the phone restart by listening the Boot_completed event.  In the receiver I do use some data from the app.  I mean I check some conditions.  Like:

```
if(getWordsNumber()>0)
{
    do sth;
}
```

But it'll always be crash when I reboot my phone.  The problem is NullPointerException.  Anyone knows how to handle this?  Is it possible to do some check by using the data without open the app?

error info:

```
08-02 01:35:11.224: E/AndroidRuntime(3194): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[wcc]
08-02 01:35:11.224: E/AndroidRuntime(3194): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 01:35:11.224: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at com.wcc.features.alarmnotification.WCCNotificationServiceReview.isShowNotification(WCCNotificationServiceReview.java:36)
08-02 01:35:11.224: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at com.wcc.features.alarmnotification.WCCNotificationServiceBase.onHandleIntent(WCCNotificationServiceBase.java:34)
08-02 01:35:11.224: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
08-02 01:35:11.224: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 01:35:11.224: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-02 01:35:11.224: E/AndroidRuntime(3194):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Code

```
public boolean isShowNotification() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int reviewCount = WCCWordCardAndListData.getInstance().wccWordsForListReview.size();
    if(reviewCount >0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat for the `NPE` and relevant code. Not sure what that last sentence means but I guess it depends on where the daa is stored

Comment: Now for the relevant code. Post `isShowNotification()` method and indicate line 36 of `WCCNotificationServiceReview`

Comment: @codeMagic have added. int reviewCount = WCCWordCardAndListData.getInstance().wccWordsForListReview.size(); is the 36

Comment: Looks like `reviewCount ` is returning `null` because there is no instance of `WCCWordCardAndListData`. What exactly are you trying to do? You won't get variable data from an `Activity` that isn't on the stack unless the data is stored in permanent storage

Comment: @codeMagic I load data from database to static storage position(wccWordsForListReview) in multithread;

Comment: What is this `wccWordsForListReview`, an `Activity`? See which of those two variables are `null` there...`reviewCount ` or `wccWordsForListReview`

Comment: @codeMagic I'm sorry that I had a wrong understanding about the alarm mechanism.  I made a stupid mistake to get data from memory.  I have to read data from database directly.  Now I have solved the problem.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Either

`WCCWordCardAndListData.getInstance()`

or

`wccWordsForListReview`

Is null.  The easiest way to tell would be to step through in your debugger and see what the values of those variables are.